# Chef Versions not matching

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chef-infra

I've been working on implementing chef in my colleges CS Lab in order to manage our infrastructure of workstations and servers. I've been running into a versioning issue that doesn't make sense. When I run:

```
knife ssh "role:workstations" "sudo chef-client -version" -x name -a ipaddress
```

I get something like this as the result:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Chef: 12.9.38
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Chef: 12.9.38
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Chef: 12.9.38
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Chef: 12.9.38
```

However when I run sudo chef-client -version on the node itself I get:

```
Chef: 12.3.0
```

Does anyone know what is causing this inconsistency?

Edit: The machines are all running Kubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have something in your shell init files that modifies your path. When running a command directly via SSH, some of those shell files don't get run. Look for multiple copies of `chef-client` on the machine.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. For some reason I had a second install in /opt, one called chef and one called chefdk. Based on their dates I'm assuming that /opt/chef was copied over when I bootstrapped the machine and chefdk was from when the machines were first imaged when the cloned machine had the dk in it. The two commands were conflicting.

Comment: `/opt/chef-client` is the client omnibus installer for servers being managed by Chef, while ChefDK is a more expansive package intended for workstations of people developing cookbooks and operating Chef.